# Chamar uma função várias vezes e retornar um array de objetos

Tags: javascript, array

Estou usando uma API que me retorna um array de objetos de acordo com o mês. Se eu executo a função na data atual, por exemplo, me devolve:

```
[{Id: 1, Title: 'X'}, {Id: 2, Title: 'Y'}]
```

O problema é que a API só me devolve pelo mês que o usuário escolher, e eu queria chamar essa função várias vezes pra pegar semestral/anual.
Minha ideia:

```
[...Array(NÚMERO DE MESES QUE O USUÁRIO DIGITAR)].forEach((_, i) => this.getItems(i + 1))
```

A minha dúvida é como colocar todos esses dados em apenas um array, se ele me devolve um array em cada um dos casos?

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, se quer iterar pela quantidade de meses que o usuário digitar, não precisa fazer essa complicação toda de `[...Array(etc)].forEach(etc)`. Basta fazer um `for` simples, começando do índice 1 (já que você passa `i + 1` para a função, então faça o *loop* com os valores corretos, pois aí você não precisa somar 1, e fica até mais fácil de entender e manter, na minha opinião).

Por fim, você pode usar o [método `concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) para concatenar os arrays retornados a cada chamada:

```
let meses = // quantidade de meses que o usuário digitar
let resultado = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= meses; i++) {
    resultado = resultado.concat(this.getItems(i));
}
```

Vale notar que `concat` não modifica o array original. Em vez disso, ele retorna um novo array com o resultado da concatenação, por isso eu preciso atribuir o retorno em uma variável - no caso, estou usando a mesma, assim ao final do *loop*, `resultados` terá todos os resultados das chamadas de `getItems` concatenados em um único array.

Exemplo:

```js
function getItems(i) { // retorna um array qualquer
    return [ {Id: i, Title: 'X' + i}, {Id: i + 1, Title: 'Y' + i} ];
}

// número de meses
let meses = 4;
let resultado = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= meses; i++) {
    resultado = resultado.concat(getItems(i));
}
console.log(resultado);
```

---

Outra alternativa é usar [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), passando o retorno de `getItems` usando a [sintaxe de *spread*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (os 3 pontos `...`, que expandem o array retornado, fazendo com que cada elemento do mesmo seja passado como argumento para `push`, o que faz com que eles sejam adicionados no array `resultado`):

```
let resultado = [];
for (let i = 1; i <= meses; i++) {
    resultado.push(...this.getItems(i));
}
```